# C# How do I play ONE mp3 audio file at a time

Tags: c#, file, audio, mp3, wav

What I am trying to do is play a sound file for an item selected in a list box. For example: item 1 plays "1.mp3" and item 2 plays "2.mp3"
BUT the thing is, it needs to stop the other audio and then play. It does this when playing wavs:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = "S1.mp3";
            player.Play();
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = "S2.mp3";
            player.Play();
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = "S3.mp3";
            player.Play();
        }
   }
```

But wavs are too big so I need an alternative.

I have looked all over to find a solution but nothing works :( NAudio plays the sounds on top of each other and I couldn't find out how to use NVorbis and oggsharp etc.

Using any format of audio is fine, I don't care. I just can't use wav.

Comment: Are you wanting to click the button once and then it plays each selected file one after the other? Or it just plays one selected file?

Comment: play one selected file to start with. I can maybe implement an auto play feature later on

Answer (score 3):

Have one instance of `SoundPlayer` and before you play the next audio, stop the current one.

```
public class Sounds
{
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();

    public void Play(string file)
    {
        player.Stop();
        player.SoundLocation = file;
        player.Play();
    }
}
```

For MP3 you can use WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer

To create the Windows Media Player control programmatically, you must first add a reference to wmp.dll, which is found in the \Windows\system32 folder.

```
public class Sounds
{
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

    private void PlayFile(String url)
    {
        player.URL = url;
        player.controls.play();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyThing
{
    Sounds sounds = new Sounds();

    string SelectedFile;

    public void OnPlayClick()
    {
        sounds.PlayFile(SelectedFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matty I have changed it.

Comment: yeh I just realised, sorry

Comment: Where do I put my file name? In the first set of brackets? "WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer(FILENAME);" ?

Comment: you call the PlayFile method, passing the file name as a parameter. I'll add an example

Comment: Thankyou, I'll give it a try now

Comment: I can't get it to work, how do I put both of those two code sections together?

Comment: @Matty I would have to see your source code to know whats going on